# HomeBrew Mac os x 10.8 throwing errors "no such file to load"

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew

Whenever I run the brew command on this Mac os Machine i get the following error

```
> brew doctor
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/macos.rb:251:in `require': no such file to load -- macos/xcode (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/macos.rb:251
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/utils.rb:3:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/utils.rb:3
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:7:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:7
    from /usr/local/bin/brew:17:in `require'
    from /usr/local/bin/brew:17
```

I have everything the web had to offer. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have xcode installed?

Comment: I do. As well as the command line tool.

Comment: I would imagine that you updated homebrew as well, correct?

Comment: Any "brew" command throws the same errors. So brew update will fail too.

Comment: remove and reinstall.

Comment: I'm having this same issue. There's an issue about it on the homebrew github page, but it's unresolved; I'm sure if you were able to solve it it would be appreciated: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/18600

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had the same problem and resolved it by

```
cd /usr/local
git status
```

If `git status` shows a long list of things have been deleted then this is likely your problem and was probably caused by a change to your RVM setup.

To fix this, do:

```
git reset --hard
```

Now try:

```
brew update
```

It might say that you need to remove some files first. Remove each file in that list with the `sudo rm` command. Then do `brew update` again.

Also you might need to do:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local
```

before you can run brew install.

I used [github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/18600](http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/18600) as a reference.

Comment: easier to run `git clean -f` instead of removing each file with `sudo rm`

Comment: I had to `git clean -f -d` to remove errant directories as well. But impressive how I forget this sequence (mostly because it happens so rarely!).